# 1 command running other commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

When I write `-kill`, it executes the `-bandio` command too. Is there any way to solve this?

```js
switch (args[0]) {
 case 'kill':
  let user = msg.mentions.members.first();

  if (!user) return msg.channel.send(`│ Please mention a user to destroy!`);

  var texts = [
   `${user.displayName} disliked the game, then soul stealer destroyed him!`,
   `${user.displayName} slipped on a banana!`,
   `${user.displayName} played UTSU, and died of cancer.`,
   `${msg.member.displayName} falcon punched ${user.displayName} 33 miles away!`,
  ];
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
  msg.channel.send(texts[rand]);

 case 'bandio':
  let usr2 = msg.mentions.members.first();

  if (!usr2) return msg.channel.send('│ Please define someone to bandio');

  msg.channel.send(`│ @${usr2.displayName} has been bandio!`);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to use `break` at the end of the `"kill"` case block. Here is the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#What_happens_if_I_forgot_a_break

Comment: ACK! Thanks for that :D.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to add

```js
break;
```

right before

```js
case 'bandio';
```

Since we are changing the command. If not then both will work uvu"